# What's the Fourier Transform of an Error Function?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

What is the Fourier transform of
$\displaystyle
\operatorname{Erf}\left[a+bx^{2}\right]
$?

I need this in order to evaluate

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\beta x^{2}}Erf\left[a+bx^{2}\right]dx
$$

using Parseval's theorem:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, f(x) g(x) = \frac1{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \, F(k) G(k)$$

Comment: ok i'll explain further...edit coming....

Comment: edit done...this technique may not work though...

Comment: ...the integral would be good, Parseval is only a suggestion

Comment: The fourier transform of $\text{erf}(x)$ can be found in another post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244744/fourier-transform-of-the-error-function-erf-x/1244745#1244745

Comment: Thanks! I must have missed it.