# Integral $\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{e^{-Ak^{2}}}{k}\sin(kr)dk$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, fourier-transform, error-function

I have the following integral

$$
f(r)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(-Ak^{2})}{k}\,\sin(kr)\,\mathrm{d}k
$$

with $A>0$ and $r>0$. I know from Wolfram that the result should be

$$
f(r)=\frac{\pi}{2}\text{erf} \left (\frac{r}{2\sqrt{A}} \right)
$$

The problem is I have no clue how to obtain this result. I would be very curious how to do this by myself.
I know that this is a sine transform, and I should be able to use a similar way like shown here
[Fourier transform of the error function, erf (x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244744/fourier-transform-of-the-error-function-erf-x/1244745#1244745).
But already when introducing the sgn function I get lost. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. By setting
$$
I(r):=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-Ak^{2}}}{k}\sin(kr)dk,\qquad A>0,\,r>0,
$$one is allowed to differentiate under the integral sign with respect to $r$ to get
$$
I'(r)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-Ak^{2}}\cos(kr)dk,\qquad A>0,\,r>0,
$$ that is
$$
I'(r)=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}A}e^{\large-\frac{r^2}{4A}},\qquad A>0,\,r>0,
$$ giving
$$
I(r)=\frac{\pi}{2}\text{erf} \left (\frac{r}{2\sqrt{A}} \right),\qquad A>0,\,r>0.
$$

Comment: I was just about to write the exact same thing! :)