# Contradiction in two ways to derive Fourier transformation of error function

Tags: fourier-transform, error-function

In [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244744/fourier-transform-of-the-error-function-erf-x?noredirect=1&lq=1), Fourier transformation of error function is derived as follows:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \operatorname{erf}(x)e^{-ixk}dx=\frac{2}{ik} \exp \left(\frac{-k^{2}}{4}\right).
$$
However, [in the paper](https://books.google.co.jp/books?hl=en&lr=&id=863yAAAAMAAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP12&dq=related:sZ9w8jqdFEHusM:scholar.google.com/&ots=EisXcfQlzN&sig=DI6VrTZpkTpbofSJEZJ1wpBVGuQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), following equation holds for any $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$:
$$
    \int \operatorname{erf}(a z) e^{b z} d z=\frac{1}{b} e^{b z} \operatorname{erf}(a z)-\frac{1}{b} \exp \left(\frac{b^{2}}{4 a^{2}}\right) \operatorname{erf}\left(a z-\frac{b}{2 a}\right).
$$
According this formula, Fourier transformation of error function is not well-defined because
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \operatorname{erf}(x)e^{-ixk}dx=-\frac{1}{ik} e^{-ik \infty}-\frac{1}{ik} e^{ik \infty}+\frac{2}{ik} \exp \left(\frac{-k^{2}}{4}\right).
$$
Which part of the above discussion is wrong?

Comment: The Fourier transform of $\operatorname{erf}x$ is not defined in the usual sense since the defining integral diverges. But it is well-defined in the [distributional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) sense.

Answer (score 1):

The first equation gives a correct formula for the Fourier transform of the error function. As **metamorphy** writes, the integral on the left hand side is not defined, but the Fourier transform in a distributional sense is defined and equals
$$
\frac{2}{i} \exp\left(-\frac{k^2}{4}\right) \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{k}
$$
where $\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{k}$ is the principal value distribution.

The second equation gives a primitive function of the error function, but since the integral over all the reals is not defined, this formula cannot be used to determine the Fourier transform.